# Configuring webpack to bundle js files for easy debugging and development in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have this config for webpack and I noticed it produces some rubbish in bundled_index.js that prevents me from debugging properly with the Firebug console.

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: '#source-map',
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        __dirname + '/app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/../../../../app/dist/',
        filename: 'bundled_index.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader", query: {presets: ['es2015-loose', 'react', 'stage-0']} },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

I end up with weird strings like these:

```
eval("module.exports = function(module) {\r\n\tif(!module.webpackPolyfill) {\r\n\t\tmodule.deprecate = function() {};\r\n\t\tmodule.paths = []; ...
```

Isn't the bundler supposed to take the code in my React components and put it in a single file? I remember that it used to do that, but I think after upgrading it it started producing these weird bundled js files, how can I have the normal behavior without getting an earlier version of webpack?

Also, when I click on the file when there's an error it redirects me to a index.html file instead of the js file where the error was triggered.

```
ReferenceError: onTestFunction is not defined
bundle.js%20line%304511%20%3E%20eval:122:9
```

Any tip, suggestion or answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that source-map was disabled by default on Firefox. I enabled it by going to about:config and enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

you should install "react develop tool" of chrome   or use this config

```
devtool:'cheap-source-map',
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'
```

[more issues](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145)

Comment: I actually get the same faulty link that redirects me to index.html and bundle.js looks the same. Is there any plugin for Firefox, I hate Chrome. Is there a way to make webpack do a dumb compilation where it just append code from the source files?

Comment: Sorry, I'm late! you can use 'React Devtools' ! [Download](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)